# Nativescript Angular: Can't read object from inside a function (this. undefined?)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

as beginner with both Nativescript and Typescript I often simply try to work with code I found in examples.
Right now I have a component that generates a Gridlayout and reacts to Gestures (e.g. Swipe or Pan). The simplified code looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import { SwipeGestureEventData, GesturesObserver, GestureTypes, PanGestureEventData } from "ui/gestures";

export class CardComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor( ) { }
    prevDeltaX: number = 0;

    ngOnInit() {
        //initialising of the layout is unimportant 

        //Calls the funtion that creates the Layout and handles gestures
        for (var key in this.SourceArray) {
            this.handleSwipe(key);
        }
    }

 handleSwipe(key: any) {
    // grid is this GridLayout Object created, cut out here

    grid.on(GestureTypes.pan, function (args: PanGestureEventData) {
        console.log(this.prevDeltaX);  //Error here
    });
}
```

Whenever I swipe around the screen, instead of displaying a 0 the function produces an Error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'prevDeltaX' of undefined`

Declaring the object inside the `handleSwipe` function with `let prevDeltaX: number` would work, unfortunatly I have to declare the object outside of it, to be able to change the assigned value and reuse it.

Question: How can I access (and change) an Object from within a function in Typescript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to capture the correct `this`:

```
grid.on(GestureTypes.pan, (args: PanGestureEventData) => {
    console.log(this.prevDeltaX); 
});
```

The reason why arrow functions work is because `this` won't change inside arrow functions (i.e. this will be `CardComponent` instance) where as `this` will change based on the calling context if you use `function() {}`.

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much for the solution and explanation!